# nix-build -A plutus-pab? Where do you run this?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-pab

I'm following this environment setup guide
https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/WindowsWSL.html

nix-build -A plutus-pab

error: attribute 'plutus-pab' in selection path 'plutus-pab' not found

I tried in /plutus, /plutus-apps, /plutus-starter.  I get this error for each.
error: attribute 'plutus-pab' in selection path 'plutus-pab' not found

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to build plutus-pab dependency, if you already have nix installed you can also follow the steps written [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/195#issuecomment-1010108933).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

cd into plutus-apps folder

$ nix-build default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab

then reboot. seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

(macOS Catalina) I found that executing the

> nix-build -A plutus-pab

in bash (rather than zsh) allowed for a successful build at that point. I don't know why or if this is reproducible.
Also, I suggest running

> cd plutus
> git pull
> cd ../plutus-apps
> git pull

before doing any builds.